# PhpStorm; how to hide line status in editor

Tags: ide, styles, phpstorm

Is there any way to hide or change those [line status](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/file-status-highlights.html#2) in PhpStorm 8.0.3?

[image]

I changed the Editor -> Colors and Fonts -> Diff, but with no effect.

Comment: Updated the question; v8.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VCS Line status cannot be hidden.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101042 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

At the moment you may only make background transparent or use the same background color as actual gutter.

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`

**PhpStorm v8**:

- Added lines
- Modified lines

**PhpStorm v9**:

- Added lines in gutter
- Modified lines in gutter
- Deleted lines in gutter

Comment: Thanks, now I can color the lines to bg color but still there's a border around :( .. it's a bit destructing

Comment: Disable VCS integration then -- that's the only way to get rid of the completely.

Comment: Posted on the ticket url you provided.